# How to pretty print xml in python without generating a DOM tree?

Tags: python, xml

Generating a DOM tree is too expensive for very large xml data. Is there a method to accomplish the printing without generating it? I am using python-2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever the language, the way to parse a XML document without generating a tree is to use event-oriented parsers. With these kinds of parser, you give to the parser some event handlers that the parser will call at specific points of the processing: beginning of a node, end of a node, beginning of data, etc.

So you can use that kind of parser and go to a new line each time there is a new node, and increase indentation where you are entering a node and decrease indentation when you are exiting a node.
Because of the way these parsers work, it will be tricky to look ahead to see for example if a node fit in a line, so the pretty print may not be as pretty as when working with a tree (or you can, but it would be complicated).

In python, there are 3 event-driven parsers that come with the standard library (in no particular order):

- [ElementTree.iterparse()](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse)
- [pyexpat](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pyexpat.html#module-xml.parsers.expat)
- [sax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.sax.html#module-xml.sax) (SAX is a well-known event-driven XML parsing API)

I suggest you have a look at them and try to play with.